# ygoth and yfonts package

Tags: fonts, miktex

I'm using Miktex2.9.6236-x64. I have another computer on which I use Miktex2.9.5496. The following minimal example works only on the older version. On the newer version I'm getting the error shown below and no PDF is produced after compiling with PDFLatex. Is there a way to fix this on the new version?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{yfonts}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\textgoth{T}
\end{equation}  


\end{document}
```

Error message:

> Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex
>
> This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
>
> (D:\Latex\MikTex2.9\fonts\source\public\ygoth\ygoth.mf (D:\Late
>
> x\MikTex2.9\fonts\source\public\cm\cmbase.mf) (D:\Latex\MikTex2
>
> .9\fonts\source\public\ygoth\ygotbase.mf) (D:\Latex\MikTex2.9\f
>
> onts\source\public\ygoth\ygothgen.mf) (D:\Latex\MikTex2.9\fonts
>
> \source\public\ygoth\ygothupp.mf [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70]
>
> [71] [72] [73] [74] [75] [76] [77] [78] [79] [80] [81] [82] [83
>
> ] [84] [85] [86] [87] [88] [89] [90]) (D:\Latex\MikTex2.9\fonts
>
> \source\public\ygoth\ygothlow.mf [97] [98] [99] [100] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.128 z0=(0,0); ygoth_e(0)
>
> ; [101] [102] [103] [104] [105] [106] [107] [108]
>
> [109] [110] [111] [112] [113] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; l.463 z16'--z16--z15r--z15l--z3r & cycle;
>
> [114] [115] [96] [116] [117] [118] [119] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; l.707 z16'--z16--z15r--z15l--z3r & cycle;
>
> [120] [121] [122]) (D:
>
> \Latex\MikTex2.9\fonts\source\public\ygoth\ygothlig.mf [25] [12
>
> ] [14] [13] [15] [11] [62] [38] [43] [60] [5] [3] [4] [29] [47]
>
> [61] [42] [28] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.543 ygoth_e(21
>
> 7) ; [27] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.
>
> 553 ygoth_e(217) ; [26] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.608 z217=(x3l-apex_o,0); ygoth_e(217)
>
> ; [1] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.675 z217=(x3l-apex_o,0); ygoth_e(217)
>
> ; [7] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.687 z217=(x3l-apex_o,0); ygoth_e(217)
>
> ; [10] [35] [36] [22] [91] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.888 z0=(0,0); ygoth_e(0) ; Um
>
> laut(606); [92] [93] [94] [16] [17] [0] [2] [6] [8] [18] [9] [1
>
> 9] [21] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.1351 z50=(x7',0); ygot
>
> h_e(50) ; [20] > 0 WSW 1 (SSW) SSE 2 (ESE) ENE 3 NNE 4 ENE 5 ESE SSE SSW WSW WNW 0 ! Strange path (turning number is zero).  ; ygoth_e->...616'--z616--z615r--z615l--z603r&cycle; z606=(x(SUFFIX0)+0.611w',x... l.1403 z50=(x7',0); ygoth_e(50)
>
> ; [30] [24] [31] [23]) (D:\Latex\MikTex2.9\font
>
> s\source\public\ygoth\ygothnum.mf [49] [50] [51] [52] [53] [54]
>
> [55] [56] [57] [48]) (D:\Latex\MikTex2.9\fonts\source\public\y
>
> goth\ygothmis.mf [46] [58] [59] [44] [33] [63] [40] [41] [95] [
>
> 34] [39] [45] [34] [95] [123] [124]) ) (see the transcript file for additional information) Font metrics written on ygoth.tfm. Output written on ygoth.600gf (124 characters, 29984 bytes).
>
> Transcript written on ygoth.log.
>
> Sorry, but makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
>
> Process exited with error(s)

P.S. I've tried to solve this with updating the packages, making sure the required pacakages are installed, uninstalling Mixtex then reinstalling it, and I tried  "updmap --verbose".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems a problem in finding the right Type1 font. It doesn't happen with TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg , yes it could be very true, thanks for pointing it out. But, up to my knowledge, Tex Live doesn't allow you to install 64-bit binaries on Windows, Miktex does, and these binaries work better when you deal with large files, and I do work with some very large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type1 version of `yfonts` is  not part of MiKTeX. You can download the `zipped` directory containing these fonts from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/yfonts), and install these fonts in a `local texmf directory`. If you don't have one, create it and validate it as a root directory with `MiKTeX Settings`, `Roots` tab.

In this directory, create `LocalTeXMF\fonts\afm\yfonts`, `LocalTeXMF\fonts\map\yfonts` and `LocalTeXMF\fonts\type1\yfonts` directories,  in which you'll place the `afm`, `yfrak.map` and `.pfb` files. You don't need `config_yfrak`.

Next, create (if it doesn't exist yet) an `updmap.cfg` file in directory `LocalTeXMF\miktex\config`, and add this line: `Map yfrak.map`.

Last step: refresh the FNDB via MiKTeX Settings and run from the command line (as Administrator): `updmap --verbose`.
 That's all (!)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much @Bernard !!! I thought about trying to install the font package manually, but it seemed that I needed to do a lot when I looked it up, so I was too lazy I guess. Thumbs up!

Comment: You could make a feature request for miktex to include the package -- as it is part of texlive there is no reason why it shouldn't be in miktex too.